# Am I allowed to put a java program Google Apps Market?

Tags: java, google-apps-marketplace

I was wondering if you are allowed to put java programs on the Google Apps Marketplace. I know you can put java web apps but can you put java programs that run on the desktop? That would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"I know you can put java web apps"*  Can you?!?  Why would you (or anyone for that matter) do that?  The Android user is not going to be able to run a web-app. on their phone or tablet..

Comment: [Here is what I am talking about](http://www.google.com/enterprise/marketplace/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Java, Python or Go are allowed. See here https://developers.google.com/appengine. But only web app.